# Traverse through mysql record to find the latest modified record

Tags: mysql, select, union, where-clause, mysql-5.7

I'm using MySQL v5.7, I have 2 tables folder structure like this in MySQL:

**folders** Table:

```
|folder_id   |  parent_id |   modified_by | updated_at        |
+------------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
|     1      |     NULL   |    Andy       |2020-12-11 11:13:25|
|     2      |      1     |    Andy       |2020-01-26 14:22:03|
|     3      |      1     |    Mary       |2020-01-25 03:55:03|
|     5      |      2     |    Ruby       |2020-01-15 22:13:33| 
|     6      |      2     |    Mary       |2020-01-18 00:52:44|
```

**documents** Table:

```
|document_id |  folder_id |   modified_by | updated_at        |
+------------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
|     1      |      NULL  |    Andy       |2019-12-11 13:12:25|
|     2      |      2     |    Janice     |2020-01-25 01:55:03|
|     3      |      2     |    Katy       |2020-01-11 03:55:03|
|     5      |      3     |    Mary       |2020-01-12 01:55:03| 
|     6      |      6     |    Mary       |2020-01-26 13:14:12|
```

So basically this two tables are for my file manager system,i need to retrieve the folder and documents based on the `folder_parent_id`,  this column is to mark if a folder is inside another folder so the another folder will be the parent. if the `parent_id` is `NULL` it means the folder is in the root of the directory. As for the document it can be inside another folder or in the root directory (`folder_id` is null). i'm using this query to merge the folder and documents:

```
SELECT folder_id, 
    NULL AS document_id, modified_by, updated_at
FROM folders 
WHERE parent_id = given_parameter

UNION

SELECT NULL as folder_id, 
    document_id, modified_by, updated_at
FROM documents 
WHERE folder_id = given_parameter
```

the feature that i want to implement is to get the latest `update_at` value  for each subfolder inside the folder or the file inside the folder/subfolder, so instead of showing the updated_at value for the folder it will look for the latest `update_at` and who modified it.

Expected result with `parent_id=null`/`folder_id=null`

```
folder_id|document_id|modiefied_by|      updated_at     |
---------+-----------+------------+---------------------+
    1    |   NULL    |   Andy     | 2020-01-26 14:22:03 |
    NULL |     1     |   Andy     | 2019-12-11 13:12:25 |
```

Comment: could you please add expected sample result too w.r.t. above tables...

Comment: Also, in cases like this generally linking a SQL Fiddle to cut out some of the interim work tends to be helpful.

Comment: @jojo . . . This requires a recursive CTE, which is only supported in MySQL 8+.  It is not worth attempting an answer, unless it is clear what version of MySQL you are using.

Comment: @RonakDhoot   see my updated question

Comment: @Strawberry i'm using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT document_id, f.folder_id, 

(CASE WHEN f.updated_at > d.updated_at THEN f.modified_by ELSE d.modified_by END) AS modified_by, 
(CASE WHEN f.updated_at > d.updated_at THEN f.updated_at ELSE d.updated_at END) AS updated_at,
(CASE WHEN f.updated_at > d.updated_at THEN 'folder' ELSE 'document' END) AS because 

FROM `documents` AS d LEFT JOIN folders AS f ON f.folder_id=d.folder_id ORDER BY d.updated_at DESC, f.updated_at DESC
```

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
| document_id | folder_id | modified_by | updated_at          | because  |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
|           6 |         6 | Mary        | 2020-01-26 13:14:12 | document |
|           2 |         2 | Andy        | 2020-01-26 14:22:03 | folder   |
|           5 |         3 | Mary        | 2020-01-25 03:55:03 | folder   |
|           3 |         2 | Andy        | 2020-01-26 14:22:03 | folder   |
|           1 |      NULL | Andy        | 2019-12-11 13:12:25 | document |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
```

This will return with reason...